# How to bind the image from the database and display the image in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a student and I'm using SQL Server.

I insert an image path in the database using a stored procedure and the image path is inserted successfully, but I want to display it in a gridview. I'm trying to bind the image URL from the database and display the image in gridview but it's not displaying the image....

Database table's columns:

- id (int primary key autoincrement)
- dob date (date)
- image (varchar(50))

Stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertup]
    @dob DATE,
    @image VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblstud 
    VALUES (@dob, @image);
END 
RETURN 0
```

student.cs

```
// I think page load event is used because of page_load event run first in asp.net??
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (!IsPostBack)//send the data client(browser) to server
    //{ 
       // GridView1.DataSource = files;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    //}
}

// insert code
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (imgup.HasFile)
    {
        string str = imgup.FileName;
        imgup.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + str));
        string Image = "~/images/" + str.ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertup", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", Image);

        cn.Open();
        int d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

        if (d > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("successfully inserted:");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Not successfully inserted:");
        }
        //GridView1.DataSource = Images;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

How to display the image in the gridview?

Comment: one of two things. Firstly you need to store it as `binary` I'm unsure what your datatype is set to at the moment, looks like a `varchar`. Secondly, once you're done school it's pretty much the worst possible idea to store binary data in a database due to the load and performance for images specifically. Since you'll be making a ton of calls to deserialize the object across the network, it's really cheap and cost effective to store it on a CDN such as Amazon CloudFront. It's dirt cheap compared to having a bigger SQL server instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a asp:ImageField in Columns and set DateImageUrlField to image property.

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" />
  <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="image" />
</Columns>
```